# How to use C++ std::map in Python with pybind11?

Tags: python, c++, stdmap, pybind11, cross-language

I export a std::map<int, std::string> with pybind11 to Python env.
But I have no idea how to use it in Python.

This is my c++ codes:

```
#include <map>
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>
#include <pybind11/stl_bind.h>

namespace py = pybind11;
using namespace py::literals;
using std::string;
using MyMap_t = std::map<int, string>;

PYBIND11_MAKE_OPAQUE( MyMap_t ); //no effect
PYBIND11_MODULE( ModuleCpp, m ) {
    py::bind_map<MyMap_t>( m, "MyMap_t" );
};
```

Here is my python code:

```
import ModuleCpp

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mm = ModuleCpp.MyMap_t
    print( mm )
    mm[1] = "Hello" # error occurs
```

The error message is here:

> <class 'ModuleCpp.MyMap_t'>
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "./py-main.py", line 9, in
>
> ```
> mm[1] = "Hello"
>  TypeError: 'pybind11_type' object does not support item assignment
> ```

Comment: `ModuleCpp.MyMap_t` should be `ModuleCpp.MyMap_t()`

Comment: @0x5453 Hahaha!!! Now you know that I'm not a python programer.